# jQuery animate not scrolling on mobile devices if viewport present (CSS might be the issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

On my responsive HTML page I have a link which when clicked should scroll down to the bottom of the page. So I added the following code...

```
birdContainer.find('.my-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
}
```

This works fine on Desktop, but on mobile devices it doesn't work. I can see the function is getting called in the debugger but the page doesn't move.

Now if I remove this line from my page's HTML...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

then it works on mobile also. So can someone explain why the viewport meta tag should prevent jQuery's animate from scrolling down on mobile?

**Update:**

I found that the link which triggers the scroll is inside a div (named pageHandle) which has the below CSS..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#pageHandle {-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;/* height: 100%; */overflow-y:auto;}
.navbar {border:0;}
.hide-scroll {position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;overflow-y: hidden;}
```

If I remove this div, then it starts working on mobile (even with the viewport meta tag).

Could someone explain why this CSS tag should prevent jQuery's animate from scrolling down on mobile?